# Unowned facebook pages are not supported

Tags: html, plugins

I'm working on a website for a company and I'm getting the following error message when not signed into my FaceBook account:

> "Unowned facebook pages are not supported"

The owner, my boss, has ownership of the FaceBook page, and when signed in on either his or my account we can view [the Page plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin).

Could someone explain how I can resolve this or provide an explanation to why we cannot use this plugin for [this](https://www.facebook.com/shopravis) page?

Comment: I can not see the page you mentioned on Facebook. Most likely it is not published, or restricted in some way. Go check the page settings.

Comment: Thanks CBroe,

Under settings it shows the page is published, and I'm not sure where else to have him search. Unfortunately the page is only showing to signed in users and stops showing when a user is signed out (returns the error "Unowned facebook page").

Comment: _“Unfortunately the page is only showing to signed in users”_ – that is a pretty typical sign that the page is restricted in some way.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response CBroe, I'll inform him of that. By any chance do you know how to find these restrictions? I'll do some searching myself but I've had a hard time finding my way around Facebook support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue fixed; when signed out we couldn't view it due to the country/age restriction of the page.